# How can I find the next date of given date using perl?

Tags: perl

I need to find the next date of any date.

```
use strict;

my $entered_date="2011-11-30";
```

In the above code I want to find the next date of the date, which stored in $entered_date variable... Please share your solutions....

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -MDate::Calc -E ' use Date::Calc qw(Add_Delta_Days);say join "-", Add_Delta_Days(2011,11,30,1);'

2011-12-1
```

In a script (not very safe)

```
use Date::Calc qw(Add_Delta_Days);
my $entered_date = "2011-12-31";
print join "-", Add_Delta_Days(split(/-/,$entered_date),1);'
```

2012-1-1

Comment: Why do you say that your script is unsafe?

Comment: @Borodin - there is no input validation, no strict, no warnings, no check what's returned from the call to split()... just sayin'.

Comment: ah OK, so it's no more unsafe than your one-liner, which I was inferring.

Answer (score 6):

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;
my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($entered_date, "%Y-%m-%d");
$date += ONE_DAY;
return $date->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
```

[ edit: changed `%F` to `%Y-%m-%d` for Wintendo compatibility. Thanks, @bvr ]

Comment: Hi, I m working in Windows OS. The above code doesn't return any value. Am I need to change the date format for $entered_date = "2011-11-30"

Comment: (It obviously needs Time::Piece, but since it is a Core module in Perl >= 5.10 that shouldn't be a problem.)

Comment: Just tried on Windows - it looks like `%F` modifier does not match entered date. If you change it to `%Y-%m-%d` on both places it works.

Answer (score 4):

```
use Date::Simple;

my $date = Date::Simple->new($entered_date);

$date++;

print $date;
```

The formats understood by new() is described [under constructors](https://metacpan.org/module/Date%3a%3aSimple#CONSTRUCTORS)

Comment: Should probably mention that this is not Standard Perl, but uses a 3rd-party CPAN module, introducing a further dependency to any code that tries to use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use DateTime::Format::Flexible;
my $entered_date = "2011-11-30";

my $dt = DateTime::Format::Flexible->parse_datetime( $entered_date );
print $dt->add( days => 1 )->ymd;
```